# How to xunit / Moq test an internal setter within a model in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

```
public class Details
{
    public int Id { get; internal set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a task where a setter in a model has an internal attribute and I have tried adding stuff like

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("sometestrepo")]
```

over the model class but to no avail. I googled for a couple of hours and I can't seem to find an answer. Is it even possible to xunit test it or mock and object so that it would allow to create an object with an Id. Otherwise how else am I supposed to fully test CRUD methods that are all based around ID parameter?

Comment: Can you use [protected internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal)?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make `private` members that you want to test `internal`.
then you can add `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("sometestrepo")]
```

if you're using Moq,You can use something like that:-

```
var mockAddress = new Mock<Details>();
mockAddress.SetupGet(p => p.Id).Returns(42);
mockAddress.SetupGet(p => p.Name).Returns("Whatever you want to match");

var mockAddressRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Details>>();
var addresses = new List<Details> { mockAddress.Object };
mockAddressRepository.Setup(p => p.GetEnumerator()).Returns(addresses.GetEnumerator());

var addressToMatch = mockAddressRepository.Object.FirstOrDefault(address => address.Id == 42);
Console.WriteLine(addressToMatch.Name);
```

Expected Output Is:-

```
Whatever you want to match
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I am asking. I literally can't do 
mockAddress.SetupGet(p => p.Id).Returns(42); because The property or indexer 'property/indexer' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible

Answer (score 0):

One solution that might work is to use a fake.

In your Test class create a fake `Details` class, inheriting from `Details`. Then you could new up the property.

```
public class FakeDetails : Details
{
    public new int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You could use the fake in your test then to set the properties.

```
var fakeDetails = new FakeDetails();
    
fakeDetails.Id = 15;
fakeDetails.Name = "Some Name";
```